# Program that asks a user to input a series of numbers and then displays the largest and smallest values

Tags: python

> Design a program with a loop that lets the user enter a series of numbers. The user should enter -99 to signal the end of the series. After all the numbers have been entered, the program should display the largest and smallest numbers entered.
>
> The user can enter any number of input value: negative, 0, or positive. No arrays can be used. Also 2 modules have to be used to display a welcome message with a program description and display the largest and smallest numbers

My loop doesn't seem to be working properly since it only works twice regardless if I input -99 or not. It also takes whatever number is input first and displays it as the largest and smallest number.

```
def main():

    #call the welcome module
    displayWelcome()

    #declare the local variables
    smallest = int()
    largest = int()

    #prompt user for the first number
    inputNum = int(input('Enter the first number (0 indicates end of input): '))

    #initialize largest and smallest to user input
    smallest = inputNum
    largest = inputNum

    #loop while sentinel has not been entered

    while inputNum != -99:

        #compare number input with largest and smallest
        if inputNum < smallest:
            smallest = inputNum
        elif inputNum > largest:
            largest = inputNum

        #prompt user for another number
        inputNum = int(input('Enter another number (0 indicates end of input): '))

         #call module to display the numbers
        displayLargestSmallest(largest, smallest)

def displayWelcome():

    #display welcome message and program descr
    print('Hello!')
    print('This program displays the largest and')
    print('smallest values of all input integers.')
    print('-99 indicates end of input')



def displayLargestSmallest(largestInput, smallestInput):

    #module to display numbers input
    print('The largest number input is ',largestInput)
    print('The smallest number input is ', smallestInput)
```

Comment: Code looks okay to me (except that the prompt says 0 instead of -99 for end of input). Please say what input you are giving it, what output you are getting, and what output you would expect to get.

Comment: Notice you printing smallest and largest number every iteration instead of printing only at the end. Also, what happens if user enter -99 on the first iteration? no message is displayed at all

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Small improvement suggestions:

- you don't have max or min limits, so you should use `None` at the start.
- use `while True:` and `break` so you don't have to write `input()` two times.

Code:

```
def main():
    displayWelcome()

    smallest = None
    largest = None

    while True:
        #prompt user
        inputNum = int(input('Enter number (-99 indicates end of input): '))
        if inputNum == -99:
            # exit loop
            break

        #compare number input with largest and smallest
        if smallest is None or inputNum < smallest:
            smallest = inputNum
        if largest is None or inputNum > largest:
            largest = inputNum

        displayLargestSmallest(largest, smallest)

    # display again at the end
    displayLargestSmallest(largest, smallest)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Start
Declare Real n,N
        String keep going
Display “Enter a number.”
Input n
While n!=-99,
Display “Will you keep going?(yes or no)”
Input keep going 
if keep going =yes then
Display “You must add -99 if you’ll end.”
Display “Enter next number.”
Input N
if n<N then
Display “The smallest number is”,n
else
Display “The smallest number is”,N
else if n>N then
Display “The largest number is”,n
else
Display “The largest number is”’N
end if
end if
End while
Stop
```

Comment: Users find it difficult to understand code only answers with no explanation. Please add some description explaining what is does and how it solves the problem or add comments in the source code at appropriate places.